# Can 3-SAT be recognized in less than exponential time?

Tags: satisfiability, 3-sat, decidability

Obviously it is an open question if $3$-SAT can be *decided* in a polynomial amount of time. But what results do we know about its recognizabilty? Can $3$-SAT be recognized in a polynomial amount of time?

Comment: What do you mean by "recognized in a polynomial amount of time"? Can you please define it more concretely (since your TM now might not even halt, let alone run in poly time for every input)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem stays an open problem (at least using the intuitive definition of "recognizable in poly time" - either running in poly time or looping forever).

Consider there is such a TM that "recognizes" $3-SAT$ in "poly-time". Then, let $p(n)$ be the polynomial running time of the TM. Then, we can simulate this TM for $p(n)$ steps - if it halts then we return the answer from it, and otherwise (it didn't halt) we can reject.

Since we know that it either has to halt in $p(n)$ steps or loop forever, and it didn't halt in $p(n)$ steps - we can conclude it will loop forever and thus the input is not in the language.

And here we just built a polynomial Turing machine  *deciding* $3-SAT$, which is an open question.

Comment: This is exactly the interpretation I had in mind, apologies for the lack of clarity!